# Create a window that never catches focus but stays on top of zorder

Tags: winapi, z-order

I am trying to come up with my own on screen keyboard.

I know how to keep a window on top of the zorder, but for a keyboard, I want to keep the focus on the other apps.

Is there any way to prevent a window to catch focus? I tried to use SetWindowPos() but it flickers.

Comment: [`WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant: Like any on-screen keyboard, it doesn't want keyboard input. It **generates** keyboard input.

Comment: Return `MA_NOACTIVATE` for the `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` message.

Comment: IIspectable, that does not work. Already tried. The next click activates the window.

Comment: Jonathan Potter, you're the man. That works perfectly, the window stops activating. Tkx :)

Comment: Raymond Chen posted a related blog article just this morning: [How can I have a window that rejects activation but still receives pointer input?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160912-00/?p=94295)